# python-sonarqube-api: How to create a project?

Tags: python-3.x, sonarqube

We were using **python-sonarqube-api** version: 2.0.0 and the 'create_project' function was available . Version 2.0.0 no longer exists in Pypi for downloading, so we tried to use latest version ( 2.0.2 and 2.0.3 ). However create_project doesn't exist in the latest version and got the following error.

`AttributeError: 'SonarQubeProjects' object has no attribute create_project.`

How do we create the project with the using the latest api ?

```
sonar_client = SonarQubeClient(sonarqube_url=os.environ['SONAR_URL'],token=os.environ['SONAR_TOKEN'])


sonar_client.projects.create_project(project=project['name'], name=project['name'], visibility='private')
```